# ProcessUpdate of the dimension triggers processing of all partitions of all measure groups in the cube

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have Account and Customer dimensions in the cube that are connected to the same measure groups (there are about 15 - 20 measure groups in the cube).

When I run XMLA command to process update these two dimensions, like this:

```
<Batch>
    <Parallel>
        <Process>
            <Object>
                <DatabaseID>My Database</DatabaseID>
                <DimensionID>Dim Customer</DimensionID>
            </Object>
            <Type>ProcessUpdate</Type>
            <WriteBackTableCreation>UseExisting</WriteBackTableCreation>
        </Process>
    </Parallel>
</Batch>
```

in the case of Account dimension it finishes in a couple of minutes because it doesn't trigger processing of all partitions of all measure groups. ***But*** in the case of Customer dimension it triggers processing of all partitions of all measure groups, so process update of this dimension lasts longer then full processing of entire cube.

I am not sure what can be the reason from which the dimension will trigger all this processing in the case of one dimension and not in the case of the other. For both dimensions Process affected objects is set to Do not process. Where should I look, what to check, can I somehow prevent this reprocessing happen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of [ProcessUpdate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/multidimensional-models/processing-options-and-settings-analysis-services) states that

> Forces a re-read of data and an update of dimension attributes. **Flexible aggregations and indexes on related partitions will be dropped.**

It *can* cause the aggregations to be dropped.

Specifically, there is an [MSDN blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/karang/2011/01/25/different-kinds-of-ssas-processing-in-simple-words/) about the different processing options, which has details of when the aggregations could be dropped

> Depending on the nature of the changes in the dimension table, ProcessUpdate can affect dependent partitions. If only new members were added, then the partitions are not affected. But if members were deleted or if member relationships changed (e.g., a Customer moved from Redmond to Seattle), then some of the aggregation data and bitmap indexes on the partitions are dropped.

Chris Webb one of the key persons in the BI world has [blogged](https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2010/05/12/what-happens-when-you-do-a-process-update-on-a-dimension/) about this as well, specifically, he has the following to say:

> The act of clearing the indexes/aggregations also shows up as "partition processing operations" in Profiler

Comment: thanks for your answer! The thing that confuses me in the first place is that before running process update I did process full of entire cube. So as far as I understand SSAS should not detect any changes in dimension or partitions and should not drop any aggregation or index? But somehow it did.

Comment: I have found the problem in the attribute relationships - all attributes of the Customer dimension where connected to the CustomerKey attribute, just one attribute - City has relationship only with the ZIP code attribute, when I removed this attribute relationship and created new one between CustomerKey and City attributes, process update stopped to trigger partition processing. But currently I do not understand why.